# Navigation Drawer and Fragments best practice

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, android-activity, android-fragments

I am going to use Navigation Drawer in my app. I have read about most common approaches of building such apps, a lot of people suggest to change only framgent while selecting different items in navigation drawer. So instead of openning new activity it is better to change fragment of current activity ? Am I right ?
The problem is that I have main activity with two fragments now.
What is the best practice to follow in this case.
To open new activity on item click in navigation drawer ?
To use nested fragments, because my activity already has 2 fragments, so maybe to create some wrapper fragment to nest these two fragments or more if it will be another page.
Please suggest what is the best practice to implement this design pattern in my case.

Comment: if you have two fragments in NavigationDrawer then you shoudln't use navigation drawer. You should go for tabs. This will help:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sww4omntVjs

Comment: Depends on the content!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the correct way is to change only the fragment while selecting different items in navigation drawer, which would be possible even with only two fragments. There is usually no reason to use nested fragments.

Obviously, there are many ways to do it, and from the UI perspective, there are many possible designs (Navigation Drawer, tabs, sliding pager, etc.)

Comment: What is the best way to do in my case. I have two fragments on my main activity, how can I use navigation drawer

Comment: You should implement the navigation drawer, and then change between the two fragments when the items in the navigation drawer are selected.

Comment: I have main activity and it consists of two fragments, two frame layouts as fragment container. How to correclty use navigation drawer in this way

Comment: Do you want to use NavDrawer to switch between the fragments _inside_ the frame layout, or do you want to switch between multiple screens, with one of them being the two frame layouts as fragment container?

Comment: Yes , I have main screen it consists of two fragments , but there is only one fragment used in official example, what should I do if I have two fragments on my main page and of course two framgent containers, but there can be more fragments on my future pages and I want to switch all content clicking on navigation items.

Comment: There is a good example [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)